# Can The Destination Site Identify The Domain Doing PHP Redirect?

Tags: php

Here's what I am doing:

1. Visitor clicks on a link on Site 1 and is taken to Site 2
2. Site 2 then does a PHP redirect to Site 3

I control site 2 only. I can do whatever I want in Site 2 code, but I do not control Site 1 or Site 3

I am doing redirect using the following code

```
header('Location: ' . $url, true, "303");
```

I have checked on all major browsers - the referrer visible to Site 3 is Site 1 (which is what I want)

My question is - is it possible for Site 3 to know that Site 2 was involved in that click in anyway (of course apart from clicking on the same link on Site 1)?

Is there any other foolproof way of ensuring that Site 3 does not know that Site 2 was involved?

Comment: how are you doing te redirect?

Comment: You can try to parse `X-Forwarded-For` header which should contain a list of proxies, but it is definitely not foolproof. If you have control over the sites, then of course you can set the XFF header when performing redirects, and parse the header appropriately.

Comment: @dagon - I am doing redirect using header('Location: ' . $url, true, "303");

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov - I control Site 2 (not site 1 or site 3). ANy tips on how to edit the XFF headers?